# Dropdown menu: All nested submenu opening at once?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

So I have a drop down menu, I want to toggle display on/off when the
'+' character is clicked AND/OR hovered over parent menu-item?

**Requirement:** *The big issue I am facing is I need it do be dynamic, so when a new sub drop down menu is created  (in WordPress) it is displayed (when hovered/clicked on '+'.*

**PROBLEM: When I open the service drop down menu item ALL sub menus open? I think it might be this line:**

```
`.main-navigation .sub-menu {
        display: none;
}

 .sub-menu.toggle-on {
    display: block; 
 }`
```

```js
//  var toggleOpenBtn = document.getElementsByClassName(".dropdown-toggle");

// toggleOpenBtn

$( ".dropdown-toggle" ).click(function() {
 
 $( ".sub-menu" ).toggleClass("toggle-on");

});
```

```css
 /*
 # HEADER
 */
 *, html {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
 }
 .site-header {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
 }
 .main-navigation {
    padding: 2rem;
    background-color: red;
   }

/*.menu-toggle, .main-navigation ul ul, .main-navigation ul ul ul {
  display: none;
 }
*/

.main-navigation .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

 .sub-menu.toggle-on {
  display: block; 
 }

 .main-navigation ul, .main-navigation ul ul, .main-navigation ul ul ul  {
  list-style: none;
 }
 .main-navigation ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

/* First Highrarchy */
.main-navigation ul {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 align-items: center;
}
.main-navigation ul li  {
 margin-right: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
  <div class="site-branding">
    <div class="site-branding-text">
      <p class="site-title"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/" rel="home">LOGO</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .site-branding -->

  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-expanded="false">Primary Menu</button>
    <div class="menu-test-container">
      <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu" aria-expanded="true">
        <li id="menu-item-2035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2035">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Services</a>
          <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
      </button>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-2076" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2076">
              <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Commercial</a>
              <button class="dropdown-toggle toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
         <span class="dropdown-symbol">-</span>
        </button>
              <ul class="sub-menu toggled-on">
                <li id="menu-item-2082" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2082">
                  <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Rural</a>
                  <button class="dropdown-toggle toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
           <span class="dropdown-symbol">-</span>
          </button>
                  <ul class="sub-menu toggled-on">
                    <li id="menu-item-2081" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2081">
                      <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Electrical</a>
                      <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
             <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
            </button>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-2079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2079">
                          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/">Residential</a>
                          <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
              </button>
                          <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-2083" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2083"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2084" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2084">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2045">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/blog/">Blog</a>
          <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
      </button>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-2078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2078">
              <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">About</a>
              <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
         <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
        </button>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-2099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2099">
                  <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- #site-navigation -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</header>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If I understand right, you need to get all menu urls from wp. you menu is static now. You need to use wp_nav_menu() function for creating dinamic wordpress menu

Comment: no, I new the sub menus to show and hide when hovered and clicked on parent menus

Comment: try this `$(this).parent().find(".sub-menu:first" ).toggleClass("toggle-on");`

Comment: Perfect. It works. new to java script/jquery, do you suggest online course for web designers?. I'd give you a check if it was answer.

Comment: Okay one problem: I doesn't work for the primary menu btn (for mobile where all the menu items are toggled (not just sub menus). My attempt: // Primary menu drop down (mobile)
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
 $(this).parent().find(".menu-test-container #primary-menu").toggleClass("toggle-on");
});

Comment: 2. Also it doesn't work with hover either i.e. when hovered on it should display and unhover it hides. Tried this and getting infinite spasm of on / off: $( ".dropdown-toggle" ).hover(function() {
 
 $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu:first" ).toggleClass("toggle-on");
});